# Access Navigation Form Set Criteria Problem

Tags: ms-access

It works fine when I used it in Normal Form
Like "*" & [Forms]![SupplierSearchMain]![txtSearch].[Text] & "*"
But When I Use it in Navigation form
Like "*" & [Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform]![SupplierSearchMain]![txtSearch].[Text] & "*"
I get Parameter pop box
Some one please help me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try-

```
Forms("NavigationForm").Controls("NavigationSubform").Form.txtSearch
```

Here `NavigationForm` is your main/parent form name and `NavigationSubform` is subform control name. You can use a `String` type variable to specify the parent and sub form control name if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably reference Value instead of Text property. Value is default property for data controls and doesn't have to be explicitly referenced.

Don't reference form name when used as subform - use subform container `.Form` property. If txtSearch is name of unbound textbox:

`[Forms]![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form.txtSearch`